# What happens after the first 180 days in 180 /90 Schengen visa rule - multiple entry?

Tags: schengen-visas, 90-180-visa-rules

There is a lot of information about the 180/90 rule, but nowhere can I find what happens AFTER the first 180 days calculated from the first entry?

Let's say I have multiple entry visa for a one year period, and I was in Schengen for 30 days within the first 180 days period. After those 180 days (after my first entry), am I allowed to enter at all? Or just 60 remaining days, or maybe even another 90, till the expiration of visa?

Comment: In simple terms, the 180 day period never ends - it is a continuously rolling period, with one day ‘dropping off’ from the start of the period for every new day that passes. Use the calculator to check your visits are within the rules https://ec.europa.eu/assets/home/visa-calculator/calculator.htm?lang=en

Comment: When you leave the Schengen area after a 30-day visit, you can return on any of the next 90 days for a visit of up to 60 days.  On the 91st day after you leave, you can return for up to 90 days.  If you have more than one visit in the recent past, the counting gets a little more complicated, but the [official calculator](https://ec.europa.eu/assets/home/visa-calculator/calculator.htm?lang=en) will tell you what you can do.